# Как при клике выбирать несколько элементов?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.s-select {
  margin-top: 37px; }

form {
  background-color: #fff; }

.select {
  color: #000;
  width: 290px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 29px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.7px; }

.select .option:hover {
  color: #e41645;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-y: auto; }

.select .option:active {
  background-color: #fff; }

.selectbox .select:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-position: 0 -10px; }

.selectize-control.single .selectize-input, .selectize-control.single .selectize-input input {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 18px; }

.selectize-control.single .selectize-input, .selectize-control.single .selectize-input input:hover {
  background-color: #fff; }

.selectize-dropdown, .selectize-input, .selectize-input input {
  background-color: #fff; }

.select__title {
  color: #333333;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 73px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4; }

.seli {
  margin-top: 100px; }

.select-block {
  margin-left: 70px; }
```

```html
<section class="s-select">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
  <form action="#" method="post">
      <select size="1" name="hero[]" class='select' id='select-beast'>
        <option class='option'>MID</option>
        <option class='option'>AC</option>
        <option class='option'>Muse</option>
        <option class='option'>Solon</option>
     </select>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Сделать именно выпадающий список с галочками можно только с использованием JavaScript. Например, с помощью плагина http://multiple-select.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/#basic.html. Или любого другого, найденного в гугле по запросу "multiple select script".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно имитировать такой селект через JS) 

(ниже добавлен вариант для нескольких селектов на странице)

> Для одного такого элемента:

```js
(function(){

/*При клике на "селект" - переключаем класс-невидимку*/
/*Важно, чтобы невидимка в CSS находилась в самом  конце, чтобы была в приоритете*/
document.getElementById('colorpick').addEventListener('click',function(){
  document.getElementById('dropdown').classList.toggle('INVIS');
});

let check;//let, потому что будет меняться, считая кол-во классов
const clr = document.getElementById('clr');//это невидимый span перед "любимый цвет"
const color = document.getElementsByClassName('color');
for(let i = 0; i < color.length; i++){
  color[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    /*При клике переключаем "отмеченный" класс. 
    Его можно потом в другом месте использовать, также несет в себе оранжевую галочку
    */
    this.classList.toggle('check');
    
    check = document.getElementsByClassName('check').length;
    //текст внутри делаем равным кол-ву добавленных классов, + скобки для вида;
    clr.innerText = '(' + check + ')';
    if(check > 0) { clr.style.display = "inline-block"; }
    else {clr.style.display = "none";}//если убрали галочку и стало 0 - делаем невидимым
  });
}

//Закрываем опции, как только с них убирают мышку.
document.getElementById('dropdown').addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
  this.classList.toggle('INVIS');
});

})();
```

```css
.block {width: 30%}
#colorpick {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box; /*важно для незаивисомти от padding*/
  padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #333;
  user-select: none; /*Бесит, когда кликаешь и текст выделяется*/
}

.color {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  margin: 0 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
  /*relative важен, чтобы галочка не съехала*/
  position: relative;
}

.color:hover {background-color: #ffe2aa; cursor: pointer;}

/*Это иконка галочки*/
.check:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  width: 5px; height: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f36700;
  border-right: 2px solid #f36700;
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}

.INVIS {display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div id="colorpick"><span id="clr" class="INVIS"></span> Любимый цвет? ▼</div>
  <div id="dropdown" class="INVIS">
    <div class="color">Белый</div>
    <div class="color">Черный</div>
    <div class="color">Красный</div>
    <div class="color">Оранжевский</div>
    <div class="color">Филалетовый</div>
    <div class="color">Каричнёвский</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Для нескольких селектов...

Переделал вариант под классы. В скрипте активно используется тот момент, что в данном примере HTML одинаковое количество и селектов, и всплывающих окон, и пунктика "выбрано" (чтобы лишний раз не перебирать через for). Поэтому такие классы не надо больше никуда добавлять на странице.

Тут неудобно смотреть результаты, поэтому лучше здесь: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/bxgrw2os/), растянуть окно на весь экран и вникать) Добавил несколько демо-строчек, чтобы легче было понять, для чего создавались переменные.

```js
(function(){
/**/ const demo = document.getElementsByClassName('demo');

const colorpick = document.getElementsByClassName('colorpick');
const dropdown  = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown');
let check = [];
let index;
for(let i = 0; i < colorpick.length; i++){
  check.push(0); /**/ demo[0].innerHTML = check;

  colorpick[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    index = i; /**/ demo[1].innerHTML = index;
    for(let u = 0; u < dropdown.length; u++){dropdown[u].classList.add('INVIS');}
    dropdown[i].classList.remove('INVIS');
  });
  
  dropdown[i].addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
    this.classList.add('INVIS');
  });
}

const clr   = document.getElementsByClassName('clr');
const color = document.getElementsByClassName('color');

for(let i = 0; i < color.length; i++){
  color[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    if( this.className.match(/check/g) ){
      this.classList.remove('check');
      check[index] = check[index] - 1;
    } else {this.classList.add('check'); check[index] = check[index] + 1;}
      /**/ demo[2].innerHTML = check;
      clr[index].innerText = '(' + check[index] + ')';
  });
}

})();
```

```css
/*CSS не менял*/
.block {width: 30%}.colorpick { text-align: center; cursor: pointer; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #333; user-select: none;}.color, .total { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 2px 3px; margin: 0 1px; border-bottom: 1px solid #666; position: relative;}.total {background-color: #bbb;}.color:hover {background-color: #ffe2aa; cursor: pointer;} .check:after { content: ""; position: absolute; right: 5px; width: 5px; height: 10px; border-bottom: 2px solid #f36700; border-right: 2px solid #f36700; transform: rotate(40deg);}.INVIS {display: none;}
```

```html
<span class="demo">0</span> — check.push(0); — создали массив, где для каждого селекта будет хранится изначально 0 (ноль выбранных)
<br><span class="demo">0</span> — index (меняется при наведении на селект)
<br><span class="demo">0</span> — check[index] = check[index] -/+ 1; // Вот и можно при клике на пункты, брать этот индекс и если был добавлен класс - галочку, прибавить к числу в массиве +1, а если убран класс, -1. А потом можно будет по этому же индексу полчить текущее значение и показать в кол-ве выбранных.
<br><br>

<div style="display: flex">

  <div class="block">
    <div class="colorpick"> Любимый цвет? ▼</div>
    <div class="dropdown INVIS">
      <div class="total">Выбрано: <span class="clr">0</span></div>
      <div class="color">Белый</div>
      <div class="color">Черный</div>
      <div class="color">Красный</div>
      <div class="color">Оранжевский</div>
      <div class="color">Филалетовый</div>
      <div class="color">Каричнёвский</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="colorpick"> Любимый цвет? ▼</div>
    <div class="dropdown INVIS">
      <div class="total">Выбрано: <span class="clr">0</span></div>
      <div class="color">Белый</div>
      <div class="color">Черный</div>
      <div class="color">Красный</div>
      <div class="color">Оранжевский</div>
      <div class="color">Филалетовый</div>
      <div class="color">Каричнёвский</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="colorpick"> Любимый цвет? ▼</div>
    <div class="dropdown INVIS">
      <div class="total">Выбрано: <span class="clr">0</span></div>
      <div class="color">Белый</div>
      <div class="color">Черный</div>
      <div class="color">Красный</div>
      <div class="color">Оранжевский</div>
      <div class="color">Филалетовый</div>
      <div class="color">Каричнёвский</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Сделано) (А меня нет нигде в соц-сетях*)

Comment: меня тоже :))   а как Вам можно написать кроме этого чата ?

Comment: немного не так там где написано выбранные цвета под ним  идет элемент под названием выбрано и сколько галочек такое там и количество

Comment: А, вы не знаете JS ?  `const clr = document.getElementById('clr');` и `clr.innerText = '(' + check + ')';` — число меняется за счет этих двух строчек. Т.е. привязано к `id` элемента. В HTML можно взять `<span id="clr" class="INVIS"></span>` и поставить его в еще один дополнительный div (над списком цветов), и он будет также работать.

Comment: я сделал как Вы сказли и при клике на цвет белый, select авто закрыввается

Comment: как можно добавить слово количество при выборе цветов добавляется только число ?

Comment: извините сделал

Comment: скажите как сделать если у меня таких блоков иного ?

Comment: @Loki https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/bxgrw2os/ - переделал. Там вроде не использовано ничего инопланетного... все незнакомые слова быстро найдутся через гугл. Широко растяните окно, немного покликайте сперва)

Comment: спасибо (просто текст ...)

Comment: скажите пожалуйста как можно сделать табы в строке количество ?

Comment: @ OPTIMUS PRIME 
    https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/976036/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B

Answer (score 4):

```
<select size="1" name="hero[]" class='select' id='select-beast' multiple>
```

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста на картинку мне надо выпадающий список как можно его сделать ?

Comment: @Loki, а это вам что по вашему, не выпадающий список? Вам в ваш список нужно добавить лишь `multiple`.

Comment: @And когда выбираешь элемент появляется галочка с помощью multiple такого эффекта получить можно ?

Comment: @Loki, а попробовать сначала никак??

Comment: @Loki обычный [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/web/html/element/select) имеет атрибут `multiple` - *атрибут указывает что возможен выбор нескольких опций в списке. Если данный атрибут не указан, то только одна опция может быть выбрана.*, *отображение* элемента в браузере настраивается через css

Comment: Долго мучился с этим multiple, пока узнал, что несколько опций одновременно можно выбрать только при зажатом CTRL... Так понимаю, нет способов его сделать сразу таким по дефолту, чтобы без CTRL тыкалось несколько?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, мышкой выделить =)

Comment: @Igor скажите пожалуйста как сделать код который выбран в ответе чтобы работал когда элементов много ?