# Подскажите как можно улучшить код чтобы были табы

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

```js
(function(){
/**/ const demo = document.getElementsByClassName('demo');

const colorpick = document.getElementsByClassName('colorpick');
const dropdown  = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown');
let check = [];
let index;
for(let i = 0; i < colorpick.length; i++){
  check.push(0); /**/ demo[0].innerHTML = check;

  colorpick[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    index = i; /**/ demo[1].innerHTML = index;
    for(let u = 0; u < dropdown.length; u++){dropdown[u].classList.add('INVIS');}
    dropdown[i].classList.remove('INVIS');
  });
  
  dropdown[i].addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
    this.classList.add('INVIS');
  });
}

const clr   = document.getElementsByClassName('clr');
const color = document.getElementsByClassName('color');

for(let i = 0; i < color.length; i++){
  color[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    if( this.className.match(/check/g) ){
      this.classList.remove('check');
      check[index] = check[index] - 1;
    } else {this.classList.add('check'); check[index] = check[index] + 1;}
      /**/ demo[2].innerHTML = check;
      clr[index].innerText = '(' + check[index] + ')';
  });
}

})();
```

```css
.block {width: 30%}
#colorpick {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box; /*важно для незаивисомти от padding*/
  padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #333;
  user-select: none; /*Бесит, когда кликаешь и текст выделяется*/
}

.color {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  margin: 0 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
  /*relative важен, чтобы галочка не съехала*/
  position: relative;
}

.color:hover {background-color: #ffe2aa; cursor: pointer;}

/*Это иконка галочки*/
.check:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  width: 5px; height: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f36700;
  border-right: 2px solid #f36700;
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}

.INVIS {display: none;}
```

```html
<span class="demo">0</span> — check.push(0); — создали массив, где для каждого селекта будет хранится изначально 0 (ноль выбранных)
<br><span class="demo">0</span> — index (меняется при наведении на селект)
<br><span class="demo">0</span> — check[index] = check[index] -/+ 1; // Вот и можно при клике на пункты, брать этот индекс и если был добавлен класс - галочку, прибавить к числу в массиве +1, а если убран класс, -1. А потом можно будет по этому же индексу полчить текущее значение и показать в кол-ве выбранных.
<br><br>

<div style="display: flex">

  <div class="block">
    <div class="colorpick"> Любимый цвет? ▼</div>
    <div class="dropdown INVIS">
      <div class="total">Выбрано: <span class="clr">0</span></div>
      <div class="color">Белый</div>
      <div class="color">Черный</div>
      <div class="color">Красный</div>
      <div class="color">Оранжевский</div>
      <div class="color">Филалетовый</div>
      <div class="color">Каричнёвский</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="colorpick"> Любимый цвет? ▼</div>
    <div class="dropdown INVIS">
      <div class="total">Выбрано: <span class="clr">0</span></div>
      <div class="color">Белый</div>
      <div class="color">Черный</div>
      <div class="color">Красный</div>
      <div class="color">Оранжевский</div>
      <div class="color">Филалетовый</div>
      <div class="color">Каричнёвский</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="colorpick"> Любимый цвет? ▼</div>
    <div class="dropdown INVIS">
      <div class="total">Выбрано: <span class="clr">0</span></div>
      <div class="color">Белый</div>
      <div class="color">Черный</div>
      <div class="color">Красный</div>
      <div class="color">Оранжевский</div>
      <div class="color">Филалетовый</div>
      <div class="color">Каричнёвский</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Подскажите как можно улучшить код чтобы были табы на месте текста выбрано ?
Пример кода нашел на stackOverflow

[Источник кода:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/975058/28748) @OPTIMUS PRIME