# Почему в переменную нельзя присвоить операцию?

Tags: javascript

Почему в переменную нельзя присвоить операцию?

```js
var a, b, s;

a = 10;
b = 20;
s = +;
console.log(a s b);
```

1. Есть типы данных string, number, boolean, null, undefined, object т. к. операция (в нашем случае плюс) к перечисленному не относится поэтому нельзя верно ?

Comment: ты можешь ее присвоить как String

Comment: Нельзя, потому что нельзя :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нельзя, потому что нельзя (с)

**Но можно так :)**

```js
let a, b, c;

a = 10;
b = 10;
c = '+';

console.log(eval(a + c + b));
```

Comment: Как показывает практика - лучше не использовать eval в 99.9% случаев.

Comment: @AlexeyKapustsin, я думаю, что этот факт всем известен, спасибо, что уточнили это в комментариях, а-то я забыл написать :)

Comment: @meine спасибо большое

Comment: @meine Здравствуйте я подумал над своим вопросом и вспомнил про типы данных string, number, boolean, null, undefined, object т. к. операция (в нашем случае плюс) к перечисленному не относится поэтому нельзя верно ?

Comment: @Leks, всё верно

Comment: @meine спасибо :) можете посмотреть один код и его улучшить ?

Comment: @Leks, скидывайте ссылку на код) [codepen](https://codepen.io/)

Comment: @meine а так можно ?https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/977068/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B

Comment: @meine Здравствуйте у Вас тоже не удалось добавить табы ?

Comment: @Leks, не смотрел ещё)

Comment: @meine ясно, извините если что-то не так ...

Comment: @meine посмотрите пожалуйста очень надо вставить в код табы, я только начинаю изучать dom :(